# insert csv data from textfieled flask to mysql DB without header

Tags: python, mysql

I want to insert csv data from flask wtforme **textfiled** with a header into MySQL table.
this is my code :

**form.py**

```
class ImportServerForm(FlaskForm):
   import_data = TextAreaField("""CSV DATA :""", validators=[DataRequired()], render_kw={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 20})
   submit = SubmitField('IMPORT')
```

**views.py**

```
@admin.route('/import_csv/new_data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def import_data():
   mycursor = mydb.cursor()
   form = ImportServerForm()

   if form.validate_on_submit():

     csvData = form.import_data.data

     for i,row in csvData.iterrows():
        sql = """
            INSERT INTO departements (name, description)
            VALUES (%s, %s)
          """
        value = (row['name'],row['description'])
        mycursor.execute(sql, value, if_exists='append')
        mydb.commit()
```

**data**

```
name, description
dep1, department 1
dep2, department 2
dep3, department 3
dep4, department 4
```

this code gives me an error in for loop, do you have any idea what is missing here?

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: AttributeError
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iterrows'

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: what do you have in `form.import_data` and `form.import_data.data` ? You could use `print(...)`, `print(type(...))` to check it. It seems you get `string` in `csvData` but you expect `DataFrame`? You may have to use `pandas.read_csv(io.StringION(csvData))` to convert string into `DataFrame`

Comment: I added a sample data which contains the text field...